# Debugging collections of compound objects

Tags: vb.net, debugging

Let's say I have...

```
Class Thingy
   Friend One As String   
   Friend Two As String
   Friend Three As String
End Class

Dim stuff As (List of Thingy)
```

Ok, something is going wrong when working with `stuff` collections. As some point the value of `Three` goes wrong in some of the objects. How do I watch this? If I watch the collection I have to open up all the objects, and that can be very long. Or I could write a `ToString` for `Thingy` to print out the Three, but I wouldn't want to have to constantly change it.

So is there a way to use the .net debugger to watch a particular field across a collection?

Answer (score 1):

[OzCode](https://oz-code.com/)'s feature [Reveal](https://github.com/oz-code/OzCodeDemo/blob/master/OzCodeDemo/01.Reveal/README.md) provides what you want. However, it's a commercial plugin for Visual Studio.

Just click the star icon of a property and it will display that property of all items in the collection.

Comment: That sounds worth paying for!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: I'm quite happy with it, although it slows down VS more than ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

Override `ToString` in your object, then when you hover your mouse over the collection, and click the pop-out arrow thingy, you can see each value:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
  Return One & ":" & Two & ":" & Three
End Function
```

[image]